# is_null in PHP still returns null?

Tags: php

All,

I have the following code:

```
public function addElements()
{
     $newArray = array();
     for ($index = 0 ; $index < count($this->listOfElements) ; $index++)
     {
           $temp = $this->listOfElements[$index];
           if (!is_null($temp) && !is_null($temp->getPlayerOb()))
           {
              echo "Player Name is: ".$temp->getPlayerOb()->getName();
              array_push($newArray, $temp);
           }
     }
}
```

The error line is `if (!is_null($temp) && !is_null($temp->getPlayerOb()))` and stack says:

`Call to a member function getPlayerOb() on a non-object`

I am not able to understand the issue here since I am  trying to skip null values

Comment: What is `$temp`? that is where the error lies

Comment: Maybe `$temp` is not `null` but not an object either. What does `var_dump($temp)` say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$temp` is clearly a non-object value that isn't `null`.  I don't know what `listOfElements` is, but perhaps accessing a non-existing key gives `false` rather than `null`.

You might check with [`is_object`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) instead:

```
if (is_object($temp) && !is_null($temp->getPlayerOb()))
```

It would be better, however, to check positively. Check with [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) and the class name:

```
if (($temp instanceof SomeClass) && !is_null($temp->getPlayerOb()))
```